# Mouse freezes over and over again for 3 seconds on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, mouse, virtualbox

since today I have the problem that (only) my mouse freezes twice or three times a minute for 2-3 seconds. I'm not sure if it is coincidence but it has begun since I installed VirtualBox. Before I was able to solve it with plugging the mouse into another usb port, but now the problem appears again. Every time when my mouse hangs, I get a new usb identification (dmesg):

```
[17578.250898] usb 5-2: new low speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 26
[17578.444338] usb 5-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[17578.452754] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/input/input50
[17578.453081] generic-usb 0003:046D:C01F.002E: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:13.0-2/input0
[17653.064963] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, address 26
[17653.832560] usb 5-2: new low speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 27
[17654.062482] usb 5-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[17654.071498] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/input/input51
[17654.073145] generic-usb 0003:046D:C01F.002F: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:13.0-2/input0
[17842.921032] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, address 27
[17843.805004] usb 5-2: new low speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 28
[17844.030877] usb 5-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[17844.039251] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/input/input52
[17844.039447] generic-usb 0003:046D:C01F.0030: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:13.0-2/input0
[17924.096795] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, address 28
[17924.898882] usb 5-2: new low speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 29
[17925.090028] usb 5-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[17925.098366] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/input/input53
[17925.098562] generic-usb 0003:046D:C01F.0031: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:13.0-2/input0
[17951.885283] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, address 29
[17952.734873] usb 5-2: new low speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 30
[17952.948076] usb 5-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[17952.956397] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/input/input54
[17952.956598] generic-usb 0003:046D:C01F.0032: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:13.0-2/input0
[17955.712738] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, address 30
[17956.500052] usb 5-2: new low speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 31
[17956.714080] usb 5-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[17956.723025] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/input/input55
[17956.723449] generic-usb 0003:046D:C01F.0033: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:13.0-2/input0
[17982.337262] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, address 31
[17983.161328] usb 5-2: new low speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 32
[17983.375096] usb 5-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[17983.383508] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-2/5-2:1.0/input/input56
[17983.383712] generic-usb 0003:046D:C01F.0034: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:13.0-2/input0
[17984.383585] usb 5-2: USB disconnect, address 32
[17985.176447] usb 5-2: new low speed USB device using ohci_hcd and address 33
[17985.382113] usb 5-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[17985.390637] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/
```

Comment: You might get a few more views if you add the "Virtualbox" tag to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I don't think that it is a VirtualBox problem. Because today I switched to Ubuntu Maverick and the problem still persisted. After I got another mouse, the problem suddendly dissapeared. Not even when I reinstall Virtualbox and run the images, I get any mouse lags.
I would have said that this is a mouse problem, but it doesn't explain why the browser froze in constant intervals (as the mouse pointer did) as I executed `qemu-img convert -O raw myfile.vhd myfile.bin`. And I haven't reinstalled qemu yet because I don't need it for now, so maybe qemu still does something "special" to the system. Moreover it doesn't explain why the old mouse works with my Ubuntu notebook. But ok, I'll let this for now, because it works at the moment.

Comment: I've have the exact same problem. I also use virtual box, but I also doubt it's related. My mouse is a Logitech MX-400 and this problem only started happening recently after a ubuntu security update. Is your mouse an MX-400?

Comment: @Gerry  
I have a M-BZ96C.

Comment: Cheers for the reply :)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the VirtualBox integration modules which provide the host USB-ports to the guest operating systems, which do not work correctly.

Try telling VirtualBox to leave the host USB-ports alone.

Comment: Thanks. I still not know how to do that to get rid of this. I hope I find a solution soon because this is getting annoying.

Comment: I removed virtualbox and the problem still persists. So a virtualbox problem?